# Subtract two columns of in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I Have a Table User

```
Id Name    offered  used

1  John     10       8
2  michel   2        2
```

Sql Query

```
select offered-used from Users where id=1

result = 2
```

I required the same query in ruby

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Active Record you can do this:

```
> user = User.find(1)
> user_offered = user.offered
  result will be 10
> user_used = user.used
  result will be 8
> output = user_offered - user_used
  will result 2
```

Comment: Can't we do this in single query

Comment: you can i did this for your reference, {  User.where(:id=>1).first.offered-User.where(:id=>1).first.used  }  or {  User.find(1).offered-User.find(1).used  }you try with find or where anything as per your convenience